# How to disable automatic update/insert in HeidiSQL when row loses focus

Tags: mysql, database, heidisql

I am using HeidiSQL 9.3.0.5104. If I insert a new row or change a value when using the table GUI (by clicking in a field and typing in it) and then I click outside of that row, HeidiSQl automatically runs an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` for that row without any confirmation. This is especially terrible if you are trying to edit multiple fields in a row and you want to copy and paste each of those values in.

I have looked through all the tabs in the Preferences menu but haven't found anything relating to this "feature". Is there a way to disable this behavior? Maybe there's some sort of safe mode you can run that verifies a query before it executes? When I used MySQL Workbench I had to click an "Apply" button before it ran my queries that were generated from using the GUI. I'd love for there to be a similar feature in HeidiSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited - or better said: changed values are displayed with a red triangle in the upper left corner.

- To revert your changes, you can either press the "*Revert changes*" button with the red "X", or press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.
- To apply changes, press the "*Post changes*" button on the main toolbar or just click outside the edited row.

There is no way of disabling this "*Click outside to apply*" behaviour.

Comment: Well, that is a shame that you cannot disable that. I might have to make a feature request to the developers. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Well I am the developer :) And I think this is just the way HeidiSQL works. If you make changes to a table row, why wouldn't you want to apply them?

Comment: Oh wow, didn't realize that haha :) I can think of a variety of reasons why you wouldn't want to auto update/insert. The biggest is that this feature has the potential to disrupt unintended rows in your table. For example, let's say I have some products on a store shelf and I have table that links the `shelf_id` with the `product_id` and has a `qty` field as well. If I enter in a `shelf_id` and then click into a different document to copy/paste the `product_id`, the row loses focus & inserts. Then if I update that row, I am updating *all* rows with that `shelf_id`. I copy/paste a lot :)

Comment: Beyond that, this means that you lose the ability to run or edit multiple queries at once. Let alone the fact that one careless misclick by a developer could have serious repercussions for your data. I would love some kind of "safe mode" that only applies GUI changes if you hit the "Post changes" button. In Workbench they always have a popup showing you the queries it will run before running them.

Comment: If you'd like to continue this discussion elsewhere, I'd be more than happy. I do think HeidiSQL is a really great project overall, so thank you very much for all you've done so far!

Comment: I was looking for a way to disable this. Haha.
I think this is the main down-side of HeidiSQL. It's scary to use. Hope it will be supported.